# Minimum resizing

Tags: wpf, xaml

Inside a grid have a ContentControl inside a Grid where I load a UserControl.
I want the user to resize the window, but how can I prevent resizing-down the window so it will be less the the user control?
In other words, user control should be always visible on the window.

```
<Grid>
   <Border>
     <ContentControl  Content="{Binding Path=THeModel}">
     </ContentControl>            

   </Border>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` properties of the Window to set a minimum width and height.

```
<Window MinWidth="200" MinHeight="200" ... > ... </Window>
```

If it depends on its content, you can try binding these properties to the `ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight` of another control:

```
<Window MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=ActualWidth}" ... > ... </Window>
```

But this will only work well if `MyControl` has a fixed size - if it grows with the window, then the results will not be ideal.